# Fast query of objects based on location and radius

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, large-data

I am developing a simple ecosystem simulation and I am stuck on choosing an optimal datastructure for the creatures.

What I basically have is a list of all animals in my current world with information about animal type and location. This list can grow very large - probably close to millions.

So, in order to implement some simple AI, I need to make this operation as fast as possible:
Given a point on the map and a radius, give me a list of all animals within the radius sorted by the distance from center point.

The world would be 2d so we are limited to planar coordinates. 
Some of the operations I also need to support:

- Changing location of animals
- Creating new animals
- Removing animals

**I read about kd trees** and their ability to calculate nearest neighbour fast.

**Questions:**

do you think it will work in my case? If not, what data structure should I use to meet the requirements?

**EDIT:**

Here are some more details as requested in comments.
The world wouldn't be too big - something that can fit a screen with animals being little circles. I should also support the scenario where the world could become fairly dense.
Finally, I expect not more than a few dozens returned per query but as I will have a great number of those queries (one per each animal althrough this should be cached somehow probably but let's forget about that for simplicity for now) this to be as fast and efficient as possible.

Comment: kd trees should work to get the closest animal fairly easy, some modifications will be needed to get all the animals in the given radius I think...

Comment: Can you provide more details on the problem? What is the size of the 2d plane? What is the expected density of it? (How many animals do you expect to be returned per query? few? dozens? thousands? ...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your constraints (a large number of moving objects and a small world of presumably fixed size), a simple [grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_%28spatial_index%29) may be a better fit than a kd-tree.

See: [Trees or Grids? Indexing Moving Objects in Main Memory](http://dbtr.cs.aau.dk/DBPublications/DBTR-26.pdf)

Comment: This seems very interesting, I'll look into grids. Do you know where can I find a sample implementation maybe? Any language is welcome.

Comment: @korhner: Maybe [this article](http://www.idevgames.com/articles/collision-detection-and-spatialindexes) will help. Also, if your objects are significantly smaller than query distances, you can use the index to store their centers rather than bounding boxes. That makes the implementation simpler and is likely to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is enough to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

kd-trees should work fine if there are many queries before the positions change (e.g., one per animal). Incremental updates probably would be fine as well, but an immutable kd-tree that is completely rebuilt when necessary has the advantage that the tree structure can be represented succinctly with an array. To find all points within a search disk, traverse the tree while pruning nodes whose half-plane completely excludes the search disk. You'll have to sort the results by distance at the end.

Comment: So basically the order of action would be something like this - for every frame rebuilt tree, process animals( create/remove, move a bit ) ? Wouldn't recreating the tree after every movement be too much?

Comment: @korhner Maybe, maybe not. How often does the AI run?

Comment: an animal needs to be able to react to events pretty fast - i.e. a herbivore sees a plant and begins moving towards it to eat it, in the mean time it spots a carnivore chasing it, it needs to update the state and try to run away. The animal positions could update every frame, althrough by a small factor.